# Login form / password reset

Tags: php

I am using this tutorial 
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL
to secure access to my web page and I would like to modify it by reset password feature. Unfortunately my reset password addon store something which makes account not able to log in.

This code is performing user registration and works like a charm

```
  $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));

    // Create salted password 
    $password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);

    // Insert the new user into the database 
    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
        $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);
        // Execute the prepared query.
        if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
            header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
        }
    }
    header('Location: ./register_success.php');
```

Login processing:

```
    // hash the password with the unique salt.
    $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);

    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
        // from too many login attempts 

        if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
            // Account is locked 
            // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
            return false;
        } else {
            // Check if the password in the database matches
            // the password the user submitted.
            if ($db_password == $password) {
```

also works fine. (not my job :))
and now my part - random string generator followed by hashing

```
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$charactersLength = strlen($characters);
$randomString = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
}

$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));

    // Create salted password 
$password = hash('sha512', $randomString . $random_salt);

          if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE members SET password = ?, salt=? WHERE username= ?")){
        $insert_stmt->bind_param('sss', $password, $random_salt, $username);



$insert_stmt->execute();
                                      $insert_stmt->close();
    }
```

reset script successfully modify db for the user, store correct salt and correct hashed password. 
Tested by showing random text and salt on the screen and than combined here
http://www.convertstring.com/cs/Hash/SHA512

Any advice how to track hash process or tips how to fix it would be appreciated.

I have a suspicion that there may be some trouble with JS which hash the password on client side

```
function formhash(form, password) {
    // Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field. 
    var p = document.createElement("input");

    // Add the new element to our form. 
    form.appendChild(p);
    p.name = "p";
    p.type = "hidden";
    p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);

    // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent. 
    password.value = "";

    // Finally submit the form. 
    form.submit();
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: fix what? you haven't told us what the problem is.

Comment: ...Unfortunately my reset password addon store something which makes account not able to log in....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse engineering from your `formhash()` Login processing would suggests that you should not hash the `$randomString`, but rather the sha512 version of it.
So in your password reset addon instead of this line:

```
$password = hash('sha512', $randomString . $random_salt);
```

Use these two:

```
$password = hash('sha512', $randomString);
$password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. MAGIC! :)